# access report field pulling from not null column error without NZ() function

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am working on converting an Access database to a SQL Server backend. I've got most of it working, but one thing I haven't been able to figure out yet is that on one of the reports that we run, a few fields show up as `#Error!` The field's Control source is:

```
=DSum("[CustomerMinutes]","QryOutageSummaryByDateRange","NZ([CityRelated])= 0")
```

It works fine as shown, but it takes a lot longer to load the report and the `CityRelated` field is a not null field, so I feel as though I shouldn't need to use the `NZ()` function. I have opened the query in datasheet view and there appropriately isn't any NULLs. I would be more than happy to provide more detail, I just don't know what other information I should provide. Any help or general direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you remove NZ?

Comment: The field shows up as `#Error!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database function (DSUM, etc.) are fussy about the use of brackets. Try this.

```
=DSum("IIF([CustomerMinutes] Is Null,0,[CustomerMinutes])","[QryOutageSummaryByDateRange]","[CityRelated] Is Null Or [CityRelated]=0")
```

If `CustomerMinutes` is never NULL then you can just use `CustomerMinutes` as the first argument.

Notice that the square brackets are around the table or query name, not necessarily required for a single field-name. (This is the opposite to the how the examples appear in the Help system.)

I always prefer to avoid NZ - it can, in my experience, cause problems with aggregate functions, or when used in a sequence of queries.